# Xcode import my framework into a project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I've created an objC dynamic framework and I'd like to add it as a dependency into an objC project.
I've read those guides and some SO answers but none of them works:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2435/_index.html
- http://netsplit.com/xcode-two-apps-with-a-shared-private-framework-in-a-workspace
- https://medium.com/swiftworld/my-xcode-project-structure-for-open-source-project-1d363ff48534
- https://www.raywenderlich.com/126365/ios-frameworks-tutorial

  Basically what I do is open the host app and drag the framework project in it. 
  Then I drag the framework from the `Products` group of the framework project into the `Embedded binaries` section of the sample app.
  What I see in the build phases is that I have:
- In the `target dependencies` I can see the framework
- In `link binary with libraries` I can see the framework
- It has been added a new phase called `Embed framework` and my framework is there

  If I try to import the framework module the compiler says

> Module XXX not found

The only way to make it work seems to add in the framework search path of the build phases, the direct path to the product of the framework itself.
For what I understood it seems that somehow the path of the framework is not taken into account, but as far as I know in none of the guide is written to change it. 

[NOTE]: no cocoapods or Carthage solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I had a wrong build settings in `Per-configuration Build Products Path`, instead of having it to point to **build/debug-iphoneos** it was pointing just to **build** .
Thus the process explained in the question works.
Hope this will help someone else.